# Converting long number to UInt64 always returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, casting

Converting to UInt64 always returns nil in Swift. My Dictionary looks like follows:

Dictionary:

```
 let response = response as! Dictionary<String, Any>

print(response)

1 element
  ▿ 0 : 2 elements
    - key : "userId"
    - value : Optional(1301400295)
```

Swift Code:

```
guard let userId = response["userId"] as? UInt64 else { return } 
let user = getUser(userId) // - (User* _Nullable) getUser:(uint64_t)eventId;
```

`userId` becomes always nil here.

Comment: Can you share the code that implements the `getUser` function as well as the actual JSON string you're attempting to decode?

Comment: check your userId value `print(userId)`

Comment: please edit your question and post a valid Swift code.

Comment: print(userId) always returns nil though son has that value

Comment: Your code has no closure for the first part of your if condition.

Comment: now userId is non-optional

Comment: updated question but response["userId"] as? UInt64 always return nil

Comment: can you print your response? What type is your response dictionary/object?

Comment: Yes, it prints `nil`.

Comment: if you don't print your data received from your API nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: Try what Rob Napier suggested. If his answer doesn't solve your issue your object it is probably a string.

Comment: This edit still isn't the JSON. Please post the data you receive from the API. We can't help you if we have to guess over and over again what you might be receiving. The debug output of `[String:Any]` is very ambiguous and lots of things wind up looking the same, particularly since what you've posted here isn't the output of the code you wrote (this isn't what `print` would print).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of problems here. The key one is that an Int (which is likely close to what `response["userId"]` holds) is not a UInt64.

```
let x = 1
x as? UInt64 // nil
```

What you probably want is closer to this:

```
guard let userId = response["userId"] as? Int else { return }
let user = getUser(UInt64(userId))
```

Note that what you've shown here is not JSON. It looks like a `[String:Any]`, and it looks like the actual value of `response["userId"]` is `Int?` rather than `Int`. That's getting really complicated. I would look at whatever code generated this `[String:Any]` and replace it with something that generates a struct (such as JSONDecoder). That's going to simplify the rest of the program substantially.

Comment: if let userId = response["userId"] as? Int {
                print(userId)
            } it says userId  always nil.

Comment: @LeoDabus I don't understand what you mean here. A JSON dictionary can certainly contain Numbers that are translated directly to Int or Double in Swift. `{"x": 1}` is valid JSON containing a Number.

Comment: @VishwanathDeshmukh I don't understand your comment. How is `event_Id` related to your question?

Comment: sorry its userId.

Comment: And I do agree with @LeoDabus that it's possible your JSON actually does contain a string value. Which is why you should show us the actual JSON that you are parsing. You showed us debug output of a `[String:Any]` which is not particularly helpful.

Comment: If you can't go to jsonlint.com and paste it in and validate it, it's not "JSON"

Comment: if let userId = response["userId"] as? String {
                print(UInt64(userId))
            }. Now goes inside loop but prints `nil`

Comment: @RobNapier my bad only Date objects are not allowed

Comment: Please go update the question with the actual JSON.

Comment: @RobNapier   Here, let response = response as! Dictionary<String, Any>

Comment: Right, `Dictionary<String, Any>` is not "JSON." We need the JSON.

Comment: Hi @RobNapier json looks as follows: {
 "success": true,
 "userId": "1301400657"
}

Comment: @VishwanathDeshmukh As I said userId is a String. `guard let userId = response["userId"] as? String, let id = UInt64(userId) else { return }`

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus I just observed in response array coming with string `Optional(1301400295)` . response should contain only 1301400295 but optional is concatenated here which causing that issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Looks like PromiseKit added that optional with dictionary value.